# SignalR handle message delivery at client side for network failure situation

Tags: c#, asp.net, react-native, signalr

I have a .Net Core 7 project which is talking with clients on a React Native mobile application. In which the users of my app are going to sell the products in rural areas sometimes. For which in multiple occasion they lost network for a split of seconds and sometimes at the time when backend is trying to send the data to the mobile.

This is my server side configurations -

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using UbuntuLifeBackendCore.Hubs;
using UbuntuLifeBackendCore.Models;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddSignalR(hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15); // Timeout for client to server
    hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); // Frequency of keep-alive pings
    hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
}).AddJsonProtocol(options =>
{
    options.PayloadSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});

builder.Services.AddSingleton<HubHelper>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("LiveConnection")));

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.UseCors(x => x
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()
    .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
    .AllowCredentials());

app.MapHub<ProductHub>("/hubs/productsHub");
app.MapHub<ClientHub>("/hubs/clientsHub");
app.Run();
```

So, I wanted to handle some network failures for these use cases -

1. How to handle message delivery when network is completely lost and client reconnects with the Hub again after certain duration. - For this currently I'm managing a few things from my side, I'm making use of RegisterUser function (which I called immediately after making use of connection.Start() function from the client side) which I have added below to register the user and save their ConnectionId in the database, to be used to send further notifications. And using the same RegisterUser function to check in the database if there is any data that is not being received by the user, if yes then I'm calling those methods from here.

```
// Server side code for Register User function
public async Task RegisterUser(string token)
        {
            try
            {
                // saves the data of a client in the database for their connection Id
// method to pull the logs in the database for undelivered messages and sending them based on their use cases

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // logging error
            }
        }
```

Client side code for React Native

For SiganlR global configuration

```
export const initSignalR = async (signalRURL: string, authKey: string) => {
  // initialize signalR builder connection hub
  connectionHub = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Trace)
    .withUrl(signalRURL, signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets)
    .withAutomaticReconnect({
      nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds: (retryContext) => {
        console.log(`Retry :: ${retryContext.previousRetryCount}`)
        return 2000
      },
    })
    .build()

  const startConnection = () => {
    connectionHub
      .start()
      .then(() => {
        connectionSucceed(authKey)
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Connection failed: ", err)
        setTimeout(() => {
          startConnection()
        }, 2000)
      })
  }
  // start connection
  startConnection()

  // reconnect connection
  connectionHub.onreconnected(() => {
    connectionSucceed(authKey)
  })
  return connectionHub
}

const receiveMessageHandler = (messageId: any, onSuccess?: any) => {
  connectionHub
    .invoke("ReceivedMessage", messageId)
    .then((res) => {
      onSuccess?.(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (connectionHub?.state == "Connected") {
        receiveMessageHandler(messageId, onSuccess)
      }
    })
}

const connectionSucceed = (authKey: string) => {
  connectionHub
    .invoke("RegisterUser", authKey)
    .then(() => {
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("Error registering user after reconnection:", err)
    })
}
```

```
    messageOnSignalR("ReceiveUploadVoiceMandateResponse", (res1) => {
      
      let res = JSON.parse(res1)
      console.log("Recieved response from server on => ReceiveUploadVoiceMandateResponse", res)
      try {
        receiveMessageFromSignalR(res?.messageId, (receiveMessageRes) => {
          if (res.Status) {
            console.log("Voice Uploaded successfully")
          }
        })
      } catch (e) {}
    })
  }
```

2. How to handle the network failure if the client lost the connection only for a split of seconds (not a complete disconnection) and at the same time backend sends the data that it needs but client did not receive it.

Solution I have tried to eliminate both of these issues - I had created a window service which runs after each 5 seconds which checks whether a message has been delivered or not and if not then it uses an API for and API uses SignalR to send back the failed message. Which did not work for me to have a real time application to have immediate update of the data.

I would like to implement a solution which can work robust and efficiently without using much resources and hasn't have to run over a window service. Thank you for the helping in advance!!